# Can't convert dynamic routes from AngularJS 1.2 to 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

In AngularJS 1.2 I have some code to dynamically load routes and controllers, which works just fine. I want to upgrade to AngularJS 1.6 and now my dynamics doesn't work anymore.

This is my old code to load JS files and recalculate the route (a bit simplified as I have some verifications of validity, but this is the basics):

```
moduleApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {
    moduleApp.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider.register;
    moduleApp.routeProvider = $routeProvider;

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'startpage.html',
        controller: 'startpageController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        resolve: {
            deps: function($q, $rootScope, $location) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var modulename = $location.path().split("/")[1];

                if (modulename !== null) {
                    // Load the JS using https://github.com/ded/script.js (Old but it works :)
                    $script(modulename + ".js", function() {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess', $location.path(), $location.path());
                        });
                    });
                }

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And the JS file being loaded looks like this:

```
moduleApp.routeProvider.
    when('/FirstModule', {
        templateUrl: 'FirstModule.html',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    });

moduleApp.controllerProvider('firstModuleController', function ($scope) {
});
```

Again, this works fine in 1.2, but I believe applying the route in 1.6 doesn't work this way any more. So what do I need to change inside the function where I use `$rootScope` to get this to work again? Or do I also need to change more? In case, what?

I've made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HnuEcblv8cyDwbGL3smh) with this code.

Change AngularJS version to 1.2.16 in `index.html` to see that it works in 1.2 (remember to also change the hashbang in the links to be only `#`instead of `#!`). Change it back to 1.6 and it doesn't work any more.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: I click the link "First module" in the Plunker, the `otherwise` part of the route is called and the FirstModule.js is loaded. However, the contents of the module are never displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is a little odd.  It was putting you into an infinite loop.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess', $location.path(), $location.path());
```

Instead of trying to trick Angular into reloading, just call `$route.reload()`

```
.otherwise({
    resolve: {
        deps: function($q, $rootScope, $location, $http, $route) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var modulename = $location.path().split("/")[1];

            if (modulename !== null) {
                $script(modulename + ".js", function() {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        //$rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess', $location.path(), $location.path());
                        $route.reload();
                    });
                });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jBh76V?p=preview)

<sub>Also, there was a minor bug.  Missing parenthesis in `ng-click="FirstButton"`</sub>

*Edit in response to comment:*

Broadcasting system events ($locationChangeSuccess) as you were just sounds risky.  To some extent you got lucky that it worked in 1.2, as it was never really supported. Certainly the location change was not a success, as your code claims.

The docs for `reload` just say:

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>   As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the controller.

So this should work in every supported version.  I don't anticipate any negative side effects.  It is simply the standard way of doing what you tried to homebrew.

Comment: I did touch on this solution, but I didn't know if it was the best way to do it. Can you theorize on why this worked in 1.2, but not 1.6? Are there any drawbacks to `$route.reload()` compared to other approaches?

Comment: My Plunker is now updated with code from this answer, and documented so that future visitors can see this in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/HnuEcblv8cyDwbGL3smh?p=preview